# The isometry group of SL(2,C)

Tags: group-theory, isometry, homogeneous-spaces

I want to find the isometry group of $SL(2,C)$ and after that I want to find the isotropy group  $H$, ( $H$ is the stabilizer of an element by using the action of the isometry group on $SL(2,C)$ )

Comment: Do you need any other conditions? Isn't every group a homogeneous space with it's own action on itself?

Comment: Thank you Keshav for your remark, i edited the post.

Comment: What metric on $SL(2,C)$ are you considering? There are several options, for instance, a generic left-invariant Riemannian metric. Or the semi-Riemannian metric given by the Killing form. Or something else...

Comment: The metric is tr(a b*) where b* is the complex conjugate. This metric is Hermite-lorentz metric